# caffe cmake error:ImportError: No module named numpy

Tags: numpy, caffe

My configuration:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
Python 2.7.9
Caffe 1.0.0
```

under ipython,I can import numpy and use it,but when following this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

I got error:

```
- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.9", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a (found suitable version "2.7.9", minimum required is "2.7") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
-- Could NOT find NumPy (missing:  NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR NUMPY_VERSION) (Required is at least version "1.7.1")
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
```

and I am sure only one numpy is installed,so anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you have fixed it.
I met the issue as well, I have done several steps, here's what I did

```
# because I use anaconda, about line 74, I comment out the line like 
ANACONDA_HOME := /data/software/miniconda3
PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/envs/caffe/include \
                 $(ANACONDA_HOME)/envs/caffe/include/python3.6m \
                 $(ANACONDA_HOME)/envs/caffe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# And I use python3 and I follow the https://yangcha.github.io/Caffe-Conda3/
cmake -DBLAS=open -D python_version=3 ..
```

Hopes work you out